# I modified gtest/gmock so it is really easy to mock non-virtual functions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, overriding, googletest, googlemock

You know sometimes when something does not work and you want a quick fix you get stupid ideas ... I mean really stupid ideas. But somehow they work.
So to be able to **mock non-virtual** functions I **deleted every "override"** in the **google test framework** and now my program runs smoothly. 
 (Not a single bug. It works as expected.)

So my question is. **How *risky*** is this method and am I ***stupid***  ?

I came to that conclusion to do it because the only two reasons to write override is:

- Make the code more readable
- Compiler checks if it is actually a method to override (protects you)

I am using c++

Comment: I like Boost.Test over Google Test.  (But I even more prefer languages that support contract programming, like D.)

Comment: I like Turtles over Google Test :)

Comment: You are aware that you are not actually overriding non-virtual functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but by deleting those `overrides` you disabled the safeties to shoot yourself in the proverbial foot.

Non-virtal functions do not get added to the V-table. This means that if you do the following:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    int doThings() { return 42; };
}

class MockFoo : public Foo
{
  public:
    int doThings() { return -1; };
}
```

You will not have virtual function calls, i.e. if you call `doThings()` on a `Foo*` you will **always** call `Foo::doThings()` and get `42`, no matter if the underlying object is a Foo or a MockFoo. Or in other words:

```
class Bar
{
  public:
    int doBarThings(Foo* foo) { return foo->doThings() + 10; };
}

TEST_F(BarTest, doThings)
{
    Bar bar;
    MockFoo mockFoo;
    bar->doBarThings(&mockFoo);
}
```

Will **always** result in `Foo::doThings()` being called (even though you provide a `MockFoo`), because `Bar::doBarThings(Foo* foo)` expects a `Foo` pointer, and the function `doThings()` in `Foo` is non-virtual.